# Use iot_v1 in a GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to write a GCP Cloud Function in Python that calls the API for creating an IoT device. The initial challenge seems to be getting the appropriate module (specifically iot_v1) loaded within Cloud Functions so that it can make the call.

Example Python code from Google is located at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/manager/manager.py. The specific call desired is shown in "create_es_device". Trying to repurpose that into a Cloud Function (code below) errors out with "ImportError: cannot import name 'iot_v1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)"

Any thoughts?

```
import base64
import logging
import json
import datetime
from google.auth import compute_engine
from apiclient import discovery
from google.cloud import iot_v1

def handle_notification(event, context):
    #Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    #Args:
    #     event (dict): Event payload.
    #     context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    #
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    logging.info('New device registration info: {}'.format(pubsub_message))
    certData = json.loads(pubsub_message)['certs']
    deviceID = certData['device-id']
    certKey = certData['certificate']
    projectID = certData['project-id']
    cloudRegion = certData['cloud-region']
    registryID = certData['registry-id']
    newDevice = create_device(projectID, cloudRegion, registryID, deviceID, certKey)
    logging.info('New device: {}'.format(newDevice))

def create_device(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id, public_key):
     # from https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#api_1
     client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()
     parent = client.registry_path(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id)

     # Note: You can have multiple credentials associated with a device.
     device_template = {
     #'id': device_id,
     'id' : 'testing_device',
     'credentials': [{
          'public_key': {
               'format': 'ES256_PEM',
               'key': public_key
          }
     }]
     }
     return client.create_device(parent, device_template)
```

Comment: Can you show us your `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `google-cloud-iot` project listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/manager/requirements.txt

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad that helped, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question!